# Defining and catching new custom exception of custom type

Tags: c#

I have the following exception that I created for my testing scenarios:

```
    class EvaluationException : Exception
    {
        public PrettyError ExceptionDetails { get; }
        public EvaluationException(PrettyError exceptionDetails)
        {
            this.ExceptionDetails = exceptionDetails;
        }
    }
```

And I'd like to use the following catch block

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    if(e is EvaluationException)
    {
        e.ExceptionDetails //do stuff;
    }
}
```

However `e.ExceptionDetails` does not contain a definition for ExceptionDetails. I've tried casting a la `(EvaluationException)e` and `e = e as EvaluationException` and I still cannot access the new class attribute that I declared for my custom exception.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `catch(EvaluationException e)` instead? `((EvaluationException e).ExceptionDetails)` should work though.

Comment: There are other types of exceptions that can be thrown so I'd like to keep it as generic as possible at the top level.

Comment: @Reed If you want to also catch other types of exceptions, than have a separate catch block for them.

Comment: So catch those in their own blocks? You can cast but you need to assign it to a variable of a different type. `e = e as EvaluationException` will just assign `null` to `e` if it is not an instance of `EvaluationException`. `var ee = e as EvaluationException` will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Specific Problem**

`e` is still the wrong type.  When you do this:

```
if(e is EvaluationException)
{
    e.ExceptionDetails //do stuff;
}
```

You're not actually modifying the type of `e`.  It's still an `Exception`, which indeed doesn't have that property.  In order to access that property, you need to interpret `e` as that type when reading it:

```
if(e is EvaluationException)
{
    (e as EvaluationException).ExceptionDetails //do stuff;
}
```

or perhaps:

```
if(e is EvaluationException)
{
    var ex = e as EvaluationException;
    ex.ExceptionDetails //do stuff;
}
```

**Taking a Step Back**

Though, since this is in a `catch` block, you may make better use of the tooling (and end up with better organized code) to separate your exception handlers by type:

```
try
{
    //...
}
catch (EvaluationException e)
{
    // specific handling for this exception type
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // catch-all for non-specific exceptions
}
```

You can chain as many of those as you like.  This allows the runtime to determine which `catch` block to use, so your code can focus on handling the exception instead of cluttering itself up with trying to determine the exception.

Comment: I would say @David 's code under *Taking a Step Back* would the best practice

Comment: I agree with your answer entirely, but, in case you've not seen it, with C# 7.0, you can make use of pattern matching in place of the casting or use of `as`. For example: `if (e is EvaluationException evaluationException)`, simplifying the logic somewhat. It's not appropriate here, of course, but only because there are already language constructs in place specifically for working with, and handling, exceptions.

Comment: @JohnH: I have indeed not seen that.  Will definitely check it out in some of the code I'm working on now to see if it makes things cleaner.  Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if using C# 7 you can do `if(e is EvaluationException ex)` and then you can use ex in the if block. https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/152/c-sharp-7-is-operator-patterns-you-wont-need-as-as-often Sorry for the duplicate. Apparently this was commented already while I was typing it.

Answer (score 4):

The casting does not work because e is already of type Exception. If you assign to a new variable it would work.

You can also catch specific exception types to make yor life easier like:

```
catch (EvaluationException evalex)
{
    //do stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // do other stuff
}
```